# Visual Studio overwrote my code with garbage on check in - what to do?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

So it's the end of the day and I checked in a fair amount of code I wrote today. Sometime during the process the computer got stuck and had to be restarted. Now for some reason both the local version and the server version of the files changed today are filled with garbage, I don't even know in what encoding. I can revert to the morning's version, but that means losing all that code. Anything else I can do to salvage the situation?

Comment: The lesson in this is just like that for document editors, save frequently = more frequent commits, probably along a feature branch so you can check in incomplete code.

Comment: @leppie rollback won't help - both the local and server versions have been overwritten.

Comment: This won't solve the problem that you have now (not sure there is a solution, other than reverting to the previous SC version).  However, it may help in future: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/080540cb-e35f-4651-b71c-86c73e4a633d